# How can I send ether between two contracts by directive of a third contract?

Tags: solidity, remix

Is it possible to have one contract (A) tell another contract (B) to send ether to a third contract (C)?  I have tried a number of things and cannot seem to make this work, BUT I am very new at this so that is almost certainly my issue.

Here is the latest permutation of the code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;    

contract A {
    C c = new C();

    function A() payable public {}

    function execute(address _bAddress) payable public {
        B b = new B(_bAddress);
        b.execute(address(c));
    }    

    function getFunds() constant public returns (uint) {
        return c.getFunds();
    }
}    

contract B {
    address client;
    address authorizedAgent;

    modifier isClient() {
        if (msg.sender != client) {
            revert();
        }
        _;
    }    

    modifier isAuthorizedAgent() {
        if (msg.sender != authorizedAgent) {
            revert();
        }
        _;
    }    

    modifier isAuthorizedEntity() {
        if (msg.sender != client && msg.sender != authorizedAgent) {
            revert();
        }
        _;
    }    

    function B(address _agent) payable public {
        client = msg.sender;
        authorizedAgent = _agent;
    }    

    function depositFunds() payable public {}    

    function getFunds() isAuthorizedEntity constant public returns (uint) {
        return this.balance;
    }    

    function execute(address _c) isAuthorizedAgent payable public {
        _c.transfer(this.balance);
    }
}    

contract C {
    function C() payable public {}

    function depositFunds() payable public {}    

    function getFunds() constant public returns (uint) {
        return this.balance;
    }
}
```

I run this in Remix like so (i.e. there is no calling code):

1. Instantiate an A
2. Instantiate a B passing it the address of the A created in step #1
3. Deposit 1 ether into the B from step #2
4. Call execute on the A from step #1 passing it the address of the B from step #2

No matter what permutations of the code I try I get the same error message:

```
 transact to A.execute errored: VM error: revert.
 revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
 Note: The constructor should be payable if you send value.   Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Without seeing the full source of how you're instantiating everything and running the tests, here's my best assumption of what's going wrong:</s> OP pointed out that they were just instantiating and running in Remix.

The line `B b= new B(_bAddress)`. The `new` keyword when used with a contract will create a new instance of that contract, not just wrap the passed address in the ABI of the contract. In your case, it passes the _bAddress to the constructor for B, which in your case means the `authorizedAgent` for that B is actually the address of the B you passed to A.execute. This will obviously cause a revert because you're calling B.execute from A, not from the original B. Instead, try to just use `B b = B(_bAddress)`, which will just get the instance of the contract at the given address.

Comment: I'm actually running it through Remix so there is no other code.  I am just creating things and testing via the web IDE of theirs.

Comment: Ahhh okay. I just edited my answer because I think I realized where exactly the revert was happening anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  That got me part way there.  I made your change and commented out the actual transfer call in B.execute while adding an event to log things and it worked, BUT when I bring back the transfer call it still fails.  At least it is actually clearly calling from A to B, but the transfer of ether from B to C still is failing for some unknown reason (to me at least).  :(

Comment: I got it!  I needed to have a fallback function in C in addition to your change.  Thank you so much!